# Add numbers in Plugin Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

How can I code for adding two numbers from two fields on LEAD form and putting result in third field on that same form in Dynamics CRM 2015 online? I am creating a plug-in and there is no function like (entity.setAttribute) but have a function (entity.getAttribute). So I am failing to put the result in third field.

Comment: Please indicate in your questions what you have done so far. Read this (http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints) article by Jon Skeet to writing a good question. 

You really do not need a plugin. You can use Business Rules. A sample is available http://www.magenium.com/Techblog/2013/September/Introducing-CRM-2013-Business-Rules.aspx

Comment: Can't you add a calculated field to the Lead entity and store the result there? Then you would not need custom code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Entity`'s method `SetAttributeValue` is protected and therefore not accessible.

Just use this syntax:

```
myEntity["calculatedFieldName"] = 1 + 2;
```